# Magento login curl

Tags: php, magento, curl

i'm trying to make a magento login with curl, what I need can be on the same server as magento
There is my code, currently not working:

```
$data = array(login[username]"=>"email", "login[password]"=>"password");
        $url="https://example.com/customer/account/loginPost/";
        $options=array();
                $ch = curl_init();

                $params = http_build_query($params);
                $def_options = array(
                    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION =>1,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER=>0,  
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>1,
                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0  (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)",
                    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=> '/tmp/cookies.txt',
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'/tmp/cookies.txt',
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
                    CURLOPT_POST=> true,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_STDERR=>$verbose
                    );

                $def_options += $options;

                curl_setopt_array($ch,$def_options);
                $response = trim(curl_exec($ch));
                $info     = curl_getinfo($ch);


                curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

This simply redirects me on the login page without any error or successful login, it seems to do not send any POST data.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

first. You've missed a quote sign at first line:

`$data = array("login[username]"=>"email", "login[password]"=>"password");
              ^`

second. change `$params = http_build_query($params);` to `$data = http_build_query($data);`

and you are ready to go.